# Sort flat array by parentId javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Every parent element should contain total count of all subcategories. It will be very good if solution will be using **only Array object methods and no using of `while` loops.**

This is the example of base structure:

```
const base = [
  { id: 1, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 2, count: 4, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, count: 0, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 6, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 8, count: 2, parentId: 7 },
  { id: 4, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 5, count: 1, parentId: 4 },
];
```

This is how it should be looking like:

```
const expected = [
  { id: 1, count: 2, total: 24, parentId: null },
  { id: 2, count: 4, total: 22, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, count: 0, total: 18, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 6, count: 8, total: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, count: 8, total: 10, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 8, count: 2, total: 2, parentId: 7 },
  { id: 4, count: 2, total: 3, parentId: null },
  { id: 5, count: 1, total: 1, parentId: 4 },
];
```

Here's my current code. I think here somehow I need go to the last level 
and then starting from last item to top concataning prev level with current
level `count` prop value that is why I made named IIFE.

```
let c = a.map(cat => {
  const top = a.filter(v => cat.id === v.parentId);
  let test;
  return ({
    ...cat,
    total: (test = categs => {
      return categs.reduce((acc, val) => {
         /* ??? */
         return acc + val.count
      }, cat.count);
    })(top)
  })
})
```

Comment: Stack Overflow also requires you to show us what you've tried yourself to achieve your goal. This is **not a place to ask for tutorials, nor the place to find free programmers**. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collection is already sorted and need to calculate the total only. I came with the `reduceRight` to save the numbers of loop and avoid mutation.

```js
const base = [
  { id: 1, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 2, count: 4, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, count: 0, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 6, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 8, count: 2, parentId: 7 },
  { id: 4, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 5, count: 1, parentId: 4 },
];

const rs = base.reduceRight((acc, o) => {
  const total = acc.filter(n => n.parentId === o.id).reduce((x, y) => x + y.total, 0)
  return acc.concat({...o, total: total + o.count})
}, [])

console.log(rs.reverse());
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stab at it:

```js
const base = [
  { id: 1, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 2, count: 4, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, count: 0, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 6, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 8, count: 2, parentId: 7 },
  { id: 4, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 5, count: 1, parentId: 4 },
];

const getDescendants = ({ id }) =>
  base.reduce((acc, n) => n.parentId === id ? [...acc, n, ...getDescendants(n)] : acc, []);
const expected =
  base.map(record => ({
    ...record,
    total: getDescendants(record).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.count, record.count)
  }));

console.log(expected);
```

The real trick here is the `getDescendants` function. It gets an array of all elements whose `parentId` prop is equal to the current record's `id` concatenated with all the descendants of that node, as determined by recursively applying the function.

The solution isn't that efficient, but given that the question explicitly forbid the use of certain core programming constructs, I doubt that's a requirement.

---

Here's another approach, recursively modifying the original array:

```js
const base = [
  { id: 1, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 2, count: 4, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, count: 0, parentId: 2 },
  { id: 6, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, count: 8, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 8, count: 2, parentId: 7 },
  { id: 4, count: 2, parentId: null },
  { id: 5, count: 1, parentId: 4 },
];

const addToTotal = (id, count) => id !== null && base.forEach(n => {
  if (n.id === id) {
    n.total = (n.total || 0) + count;
    addToTotal(n.parentId, count);
  }
});
base.forEach(n => {
  n.total = (n.total || 0) + n.count;
  addToTotal(n.parentId, n.count);
});

console.log(base);
```